# Mathematical description of rotations and translations in complex domain

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am self reading textbook "Visual Complex Analysis" by Needham
And I am unable to "solve" this part . Like in terms of understanding I have a good image of how these translations and rotations happen but I don't know how to actually like write it in mathematical form
[image]

I got where this k come from but I have no idea where **c** comes out Similarly i am trying but i cannot figure out what **p** should be ?
[image]

Similarly this **v** here makes no sense to me and i cannot interpret what this means ? So plz help?!

Comment: For $c$ and $p$ note that they are the centres of rotation so they are the points which are invariant under the transformation

Comment: @TonyPizza can u describe how c=v/(1-e^ia) like mathematically step by step ? v is translation and alpha is rotation how combination such as c can be obtained in a way that these center of rotation point are invariant under transformation!?

Comment: $c$ in the first pic can be calculated as follows. The transformation first rotates everything by $\alpha$ with $0$ as the center and then translates by $v$. So $c$ gets mapped to $e^{i\alpha}c + v$. But this transformation is supposed to be rotation around $c$ so $c$ has to be fixed. Hence $e^{i\alpha}c + v = c$. From this you can get what is $c$. You can get $p$ in a similar manner. For everything in 2nd pic, ideas are still all same but you just need some more calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have no idea where $c$ comes from.

We have:
$$(\mathcal{T}_v \circ \mathcal{R}^\alpha_0)(z) = \mathcal{T}_v(e^{i\alpha}z) = e^{i\alpha} z + v.$$
The author claims that this can be expressed as a rotation at a point $c$, also by $\alpha$. From before in the text,
$$\mathcal{R}_c^\alpha(z) = e^{i\alpha}(z - c) + c.$$
Now, for the author's claim to be correct, there needs to be a $c \in \Bbb{C}$ such that the two expressions are an identity, regardless of $z$, $\alpha$, or $v$. We can solve for $c$ by equating:
$$e^{i\alpha}z + v = e^{i\alpha}(z - c) + c = e^{i\alpha}z + c\left(1 - e^{i\alpha} \right).$$
Cancelling $e^{i\alpha} z$ from both sides, and dividing by $1 - e^{i\alpha}$, we get
$$c = \frac{v}{1 - e^{i \alpha}}$$
as expected. (Note: an implicit assumption was made that $e^{i\alpha} \neq 1$, i.e. $\mathcal{R}_0^\alpha$ is not the trivial rotation. Otherwise, we cannot divide by $1 - e^{i \alpha}$, and composing $\mathcal{R}_0^\alpha$ with a translation definitely does **not** produce a rotation).

Another important note: the $c$ does not depend on $z$. If it did, then we could not say the composition was a rotation with centre $c$, because the centre should not be changing depending on the vector we are rotating!

> Similarly, I am trying but i cannot figure out what $p$ should be

A similar method will produce such a $p$. I won't compute it, as I'm hoping you have the tools to do it for yourself now. Let me know with a comment if you get stuck again.

> Similarly this $v$ here makes no sense to me and I cannot interpret what this means

The $v$ is not supposed to be deep and meaningful. It's a complex number, depending on the two rotations $\mathcal{R}_a^\theta$ and $\mathcal{R}_b^\phi$ (or more precisely, the centres $a, b$ and angles of rotation $\theta$, $\phi$ respectively). Geometrically, the expression $e^{i(\theta + \phi)}z + v$ is just a rotation about the origin by $\theta + \phi$, followed by a translation by this vector/complex number $v$ (whatever it comes to be).

Just like before, to find whatever this $v$ must be, you can just equate:
$$\mathcal{R}_b^\phi \mathcal{R}_a^\theta z = e^{i(\theta + \phi)i}z + v$$
and solve. The left hand side requires some unpacking:
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{LHS} &= \mathcal{R}_b^\phi \mathcal{R}_a^\theta z \\
&= e^{i \phi} \left(\mathcal{R}_a^\theta z - b\right) + b \\
&= e^{i \phi} \left(e^{i\theta}\left(z - a\right) - a - b\right) + b.
\end{align*}
When you expand all of that, and subtract $e^{i(\theta + \phi)i}z$ from both sides, you should get that $v$ takes the desired form.